# Excel formulas to javascript

Tags: javascript, excel-formula

Im trying to use an excel formula into my javascript code but cannot get the correct result, here is the formula in excel:

```
(C4-(C8/C6))*(1-((1+(C5/12))^-C6))/(C5/12)+C8+C7
```

and how i try it in javascript:

```
(737-(50000/300))*(1-(Math.pow((1+(0.02/12)),-300)))/(0.02/12)+50000+10000
```

or

```
(737-(50000/300))*(1-((1+(0.02/12))**-300))/(0.02/12)+50000+10000
```

Both attempt give me same result but this result is not the same as in excel, any idea?

Javascript give me 194558.80507389922 but excel give me 191516,666

[image]

Comment: are you sure the excel formula is working as you wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try it myself in Excel, the formula produces `194559,8051` (same as JS).

When I change C5 from `0,02` to `0,022` then the formula produces `191516,666` (same as your Excel).

Conclusion -> your C5 is actually `0,022`, or something very close to it. Please make sure your cells are set to show as many decimals as needed to avoid display-only rounding.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right, switched the cells format to 3 decimals and it was 0.022.. thanks you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Same result to the 4 decimals my Excel rounded with default and same result to 7 decimals

NOTE: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

```js
const C4 = 737;
const C5 = 0.02;
const C6 = 300;
const C7 = 10000;
const C8 = 50000;

// (C4-(C8/C6))*(1-((1+(C5/12))^-C6))/(C5/12)+C8+C7         = 194558,8051 in my Office 365 Excel
                                                           // 194558,805073901 - with 9 decimals
console.log(
(C4-(C8/C6))*(1-(Math.pow((1+(C5/12)),-C6)))/(C5/12)+C8+C7 // 194558.80507389922
)

console.log(
(C4-(C8/C6))*(1-((1+(C5/12))**-C6))/(C5/12)+C8+C7          // 194558.80507389922
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, im indeed getting 194558.80507389922 but what bother me is that excel give me 191516,666 ... adding the screen in initial message

Comment: I got 194558,805073901 in my Excel Office 365 with the values I displayed and your formula